# Comma in such phrases like "большáя, если не бóльшая часть"

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need to place a comma after the word **бóльшая** here?:

> А что до "геологов" (уверен, что большáя, если не **бóльшая** часть из них
>   никогда не были профессиональными геологами), то я им просто не верю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the comma after *бо́льшая* would not be superfluous.

> (уверен, что большáя, если не бóльшая, часть из них никогда не были профессиональными геолагами)

The general empirical rule is that: if you can cut some clause out of sentence without losing grammatical and semantic consistency, it should be enclosed in some punctuation symbols (usually commas) on both sides.

If there would not be parentheses already, you can also enclose если-clause in them:

> ...уверен, что большáя (если не бóльшая) часть из них никогда не были профессиональными геолагами...

Since I cannot find this very case in any grammar guide, a couple of quotes from publications, which had undoubtedly passed excellent proofreading, would be suitable:

> ...в которой Бернштейн ревизовал теорию Маркса и заявлял, что значительная**,** если не бо́льшая**,** часть действующих в России социал-демократов якобы решительно присоединилась к его точке зрения...
>   [В. И. Ленин. ПСС, том 4 — М.:Политиздат, 1969 — С. IX]
>
> В этом состоит главнейшее**,** если не единственное**,** средство окончательно преодолеть капитализм и привычки, созданные господством частной собственности на средства производства.
>   [В. И. Ленин. ПСС, том 38 — М.:Политиздат, 1969 — С. 119]
>
> ...такие объекты, если они вообще пригодны для обороны, могут быть приспособлены к оказанию не меньшего**,** если не большего**,** сопротивления, чем любое полевое укрепление, сооруженное по всем правилам военного искусства.
>   [К. Маркс и Ф. Энгельс. Сочинения, том 14 — М.:Политиздат, 1959 — С. 273]
>
> ...уже проделав в течение трех месяцев — первых самых трудных трех месяцев — работу по организации, имея неплохие шансы получить еще один **—** если не два **—** месяц передышки...
>   [К. Маркс и Ф. Энгельс. Сочинения, том 17 — М.:Политиздат, 1960 — С. 205]

Note the last – если-clause is enclosed not in commas but in dashes. Why? Most probably because grammatical number of *два* is not matched to *месяц*. In other examples both adjectives – before and after *если не* – are in concord with determined word.

P. S. Yep, I use canonical editions of Classics of Marxism as grammar reference book :-)